# stretch a image as a view's background

Tags: ios

I made a custom UITableViewCell and its height is dynamic, I want to stretch a image to fit its height, how to use UIEdgeInsetsMake for it? I tried many EdgeInsets and the view looks weird, it seemed just repeat the image vertically.

```
UIImage *cell_bg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg"];

cell_bg=[cell_bg resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 300)];

UIImageView *backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cell_bg];

self.backgroundView=backgroundView;
[backgroundView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like as below:

[[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:yourvalue topCapHeight:yourvalue];

thanks

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 5.0,Use the resizableImageWithCapInsets: instead.